# Firefox like address bar in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, software-rec, awesomebar

Firefox's [AwesomeBar](http://blog.mozilla.com/blog/2008/04/21/a-little-something-awesome-about-firefox-3/) searches history including the titles of pages incrementally. How can I get Chrome to also search the titles in the history?

For example, for this very page, in Firefox, I can search "Firefox Lik" and this page's address shows up in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Is there any Chrome extension that can do this?

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using?  Are you using default settings so it will store your history?  If I open up a new tab in Chrome and type *Firefox Lik* it will suggest this page (*Firefox Like address bar in Chrome - Super User*) because it is in my history.

Comment: I am using the chrome 5 beta on Windows. Settings are default.

Comment: Chrome beta is up to v. 11 now. Perhaps you should upgrade.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Chrome's Omnibar behave more like the Firefox AwesomeBar](http://superuser.com/questions/120885/make-chromes-omnibar-behave-more-like-the-firefox-awesomebar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [plugin](http://www.howtogeek.com/news/add-firefoxs-awesome-bar-bookmark-search-function-to-chrome-and-iron/3958/)

Update:  in my experience, chrome has gotten a lot better at this in the past year or so.   Now it is as good as firefox for most use cases.

Comment: Unfortunately that currently only searches bookmarks, not the history.

Comment: This seems to be doing the job, along with sirlancelot's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome 11 has a flag called "Enable better omnibox history matching", you can enable it by typing `about:flags` in the address bar and clicking "Enable"

Comment: I can’t find it. What version exactly?

Comment: It only searches history though - bookmarks are still not searched. The awesome bar in firefox is all that's holding me back to move to Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know exactly what version is required, but newer version of Chrome do indeed include items from the history (at least recent history, though I haven’t tested the extent) in the suggestions for the Omnibox drop-down. The catch is that if you have a large history, it may take a few seconds for Chrome to retrieve them since it offers more immediate things first (like open tabs, MRU pages, MFU pages, etc.)