# How can Chrome search among the title/URL of already opened tabs, like Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, search, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

When you manage many tabs, Firefox has a great feature to avoid opening the same page again, if it's already opened in some other tab: as you type a URL (or title page), Firefox shows in its Awesomebar that the page is already opened in another tab, and you can instead go to that tab.

How can Chrome do that, search among its opened tabs? I've seen [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/120885/make-chromes-omnibar-behave-more-like-the-firefox-awesomebar) about [searching in the history](https://superuser.com/questions/138217/firefox-like-address-bar-in-chrome) and there are extensions for [searching among bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesomebar/epfjibmdcelinmbfeimnfeeggpebleje/details), but those that can search among already opened tabs leave a lot to be desired:

- Search Plus can only [search among tabs in the current window](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-plus/cdpohbejnbclggljmoijjcpdhbaaijfm/reviews), is abandoned, and isn't open source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that this is now a feature in Chrome, there is a "Switch to tab" option in the url bar when what you are typing matches the title of any open tab you have open.

Answer (score 2):

Tab Ahead looks like the holy grail. Takie it for a spin - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-ahead/naoajjeoiblmpegfelhkapanmmaaghmi?hl=en

Comment: Excellent! It's [open source](https://github.com/janraasch/tab-ahead) and does the job.

Comment: At the same time, it would be nice if it was in the main address bar. I think what we really want, is that instead of typing in "gmail.com" in the address bar for the thousandth time today, it will show up as I'm typing in the address bar, and I can key down and hit enter to go to the existing tab.

Comment: Firefox shows active tabs in suggestions. I'm fairly confident Chrome does that too. The main hurdle here is that the list of suggestions is constantly jumping as you type and even then the tab suggestion is after mistyping suggestions (so 4-6th in the list).

Answer (score 1):

One extension that does this, though very poorly, is Omnitab. You type `o` then some part of the URL, and choose "Run Omnitab command" from the drop down. What's wrong with it:

1. You'll jump to one of the open tabs that matches the query
2. There's no way to preview where you'll go
3. You can't select any other match.
4. The extension has access to all your tabs, but isn't open sourced like [Fauxbar](https://code.google.com/p/fauxbar/).

Answer (score 1):

Fauxbar seems a little better:

1. Open source
2. Shows "Switch to tab" for matched results

Yet it [doesn't always search among open tabs first](https://code.google.com/p/fauxbar/issues/detail?id=150).