# Chrome: how to get the Omnibar to suggest URLs from the history based on the page title?

Tags: google-chrome

How can the Omnibar in Chrome be made to act like the AwesomeBar in Firefox? Specifically, Chrome doesn't seem to recall Google Docs from the history when I type some of the text from the doc's title (which isn't part of the url but only in the html title.)

Comment: I use Chrome Canary. It matches page titles from history to some extent. Though that's not comparable to Firefox. I believe Chrome team is working on it.

Comment: just tried it - it also doesn't search by title of docs in the history...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Chrome's Omnibar behave more like the Firefox AwesomeBar](http://superuser.com/questions/120885/make-chromes-omnibar-behave-more-like-the-firefox-awesomebar)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a option in chrome. Go to

> about:flags

Set **Aggressive history URL scoring** to *Enabled*. Now Chrome should match title of the history to some extent (I am saying again it's not comparable to Firefox).

[image: Chrome flags page]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a complete change of behavior is possible at the moment, unfortunately. You can try the  [Fauxbar Lite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bfimmnpbjccjihohjkimphfmmebffbmk) extension, which can be triggered directly in the Omnibar by typing `f <your query goes here>`. It claims to use the AwesomeBar algorithm to search history, bookmarks, and open tabs, and it hasn't failed me so far after months of use!

Fauxbar will also add an icon to your toolbar; clicking it will bring up a page with an AwesomeBar clone. If you ever want to replace Chrome's New Tab page with the Fauxbar page, get the [full extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hibkhcnpkakjniplpfblaoikiggkopka) instead.

Comment: no, it doesn't search in google doc titles for me (at least on chrome 18 beta)

Comment: Just tested now, it DOES find google docs titles

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Extension "Better History" from Roy Kolak, with which you can browse your history eifficiently, also it will include the results from your history in suggestion url's. Hope this helps.

Comment: nope. unrelated to what i asked

Comment: I dunno if you tried it, But its working for me.. opened a doc from google docs, and can see the link using title of document from history.

Comment: i tried it but doesn't work for me. weird