# Why am I missing entries in Chrome history and Omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Chrome 18.0.1025.11 beta-m, but I've had this problem since switching from Firefox over at least 5 releases.

I've found that history entries are often not reflected in the Omnibox when typing either document titles or URLs and the history search has the same behaviour. I can see the entries in the history, but they're not reflected in search results:

[image: Chrome history vs history search results]

Edit: Embedded screenshot showing the problem. No matter how many times I visit the affected sites, they're never reflected in history search or the Omnibox. I don't think this is an Omnibox problem, but something more fundamental w/ history/search.

No matter how specific my search, the missing entries are never displayed. I rely on the browser history constantly for finding pages I've visited to avoid having to bookmark them, but there are dozens of pages affected and it's a real productivity killer.

I've already tried nuking the history completely (ie. uninstalling Chrome, removing all user data, reinstalling) with no luck.

Has anyone else had a similar experience?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Chrome's Omnibar behave more like the Firefox AwesomeBar](http://superuser.com/questions/120885/make-chromes-omnibar-behave-more-like-the-firefox-awesomebar)

Comment: @Synetech actually the real problem is the history search itself, none of the extensions or workarounds will address this because these items aren't reflected in search results in about:history.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, this is normal. For whatever reason, the Chromium team has yet to implement a comparable addressbar/history feature to Firefox's.

In the meantime, you can try the [Better Omnibox](https://github.com/cfinke/Better-Omnibox) extension to improve history and bookmark support in the Omnibox.

Comment: Good idea, but it looks like the history search problem affects Better Omnibox too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Fauxbar](http://code.google.com/p/fauxbar) extension?

Your problem is partially caused by the Chromium team limiting the number of values returned in the Omnibox to 6. Which is really frustrating. Making the situation worse is that if you have existing search entries these will take up slots in the 6 results.

The can effectively make the Chrome omnibar useless.